# How to find the matrix of Linear Transformation with respect to S given the linear transformations of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I was trying to attempt the following question:
$Let, L: $P1 -> P1 be defined by:

$L(t+1) = t - 1, L(t-1) = 2t + 1 $

A) Find the matrix of L with respect to the basis $S = {t+1, t-1}$ for  P1.

B) Find $L(2t+3)$ using definition of L and Also using the matrix obtained in (A)

Now I tried to approach the solution by using the V1 V2 | L(V1) | (L(V1) to find the matrix

Then I tried the (B) Part but the value by matrix and definition don't match

The solution is appended below as a reference, Sorry couldn't write all of that using the Text hence a picture is appended:

[image: Start]

[image: Page 2]

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Your title is very confusing, but perhaps the place to start is with the body of your Question.  You began by defining a linear transformation $L$ from its action on a basis $S$, but notably absent is any mention of what (vector space) `P1` is.  More than likely you are asked to represent both input and output of $L$ in coordinates using (ordered) basis $S$.  See [this brief introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and its links for how to post here using mathematical notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix is correct. You also start correctly by representing $2t+3$ in the basis:
$$2t+3 = 2.5v_1 - 0.5v_2.$$
Hence by linearity
$$L(2t+3) = L(2.5v_1 - 0.5v_2) = 2.5L(v_1) - 0.5L(v_2) = 2.5(t-1)-0.5(2t+1) = 1.5t-3.$$
This should be your final answer.

Lets try to get the same result using the matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1.5\\\ 1 & 0.5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2.5\\ -0.5 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -0.75\\ 2.25 \end{pmatrix}.$$
This is in our special basis $\{t+1,t-1\}.$ Let's bring this back to the normal basis $\{1,t\}:$
$$-0.75(t+1) + 2.25(t-1) = 1.5t-3.$$

Comment: -0.75t + 4.50t = 3.75t right
How is it 1.5 here?

Comment: Upsie I wrote the wrong special basis, it should be $\{v_1,v_2\}$ not $\{L(v_1),L(v_2)\}$. It is now corrected.